# .htaccess rewrite multiple get variables

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to rewrite the following URLs using a .htaccess file:

```
a) vic/teams/index.php?suburb=glenroy&teamname=golden-boys
b) vic/teams/index.php?suburb=east-melbourne&teamname=chargers
c) vic/teams/index.php?suburb=west-ivanhoe&teamname=red-dogs
d) vic/teams/index.php?suburb=geelong&teamname=rhinos
```

to

```
a) vic/teams/glenroy-golden-boys
b) vic/teams/east-melbourne-chargers
c) vic/teams/west-ivanhoe-red-dogs
d) vic/teams/geelong-rhinos
```

I currently use this but it only works for some of the examples:

```
RewriteRule ^vic/teams/(.*)-(.*)$  vic/teams/index.php?suburb=$1&teamname=$2
```

Could anyone suggest a better rule? Thanks!

Comment: You need to use any character other than hyphen as a separator since `-` is also used in the parameters. So something like `vic/teams/east-melbourne/chargers` will be better

Comment: There is no way for a computer to discern between a dash in the suburb name or a dash in the team name unless you give it a dictionary that tells it which possible names there are. Even if you had that, adding that to a mod-rewrite rule would be hard (if possible at all). This approach is not going to work.